# PowerBI: Alternative solutions to dynamic formatting other than “dynamic” format or “calculation groups”

Tags: powerbi, formatting

If I have a measure which dynamically switches the metric as per end user selection and if I have a mixed set of Dax measures calculating rates and revenues, how can I add “%” sign and “$” at the end of percentage measure and revenue measure respectively on a bar chart?
I am looking for a solution other than the “dynamic” option in format tab and “calculation groups”. Could anybody help here?

Comment: Would dynamic format strings work for you? [Create dynamic format strings for measures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-dynamic-format-strings)

Comment: Nope, that is the option of using the "dynamic" format and I am looking for another solution if I am not supposed to use the version with the dynamic formatting

Comment: Explain why dynamic format strings can't be used as this is the usual approach (hence why the feature was developed).

Comment: As this feature is unavailable in the Jan2023 desktop version that I need to use. Hence looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: It is available, you need to enable it. File > Options & Settings > Options > GLOBAL > Preview Features > enable `Dynamic format string for measures`

Comment: I did check this option too but I don't find "Preview Features" under GLOBAL in this version.

Comment: I believe this feature was available from April 2023 version. Current version is now Dec 2023. Are you unable or not allowed to use a later version?

Comment: Yeah, not allowed currently (only 1 version) to collaborate with all others in the organization. Hence, curious to know if there could be any other trick to solve this.